# How many expressroute circuits are needed?

Tags: azure

To connect 2 datacenters that are already linked through a Point to Point link, to a Azure DC which in turn has a secondary Azure DC for DR through ExpressRoute, what is the minimum number of circuits that would be needed?

To rephrase, 2 linked DCs in separate cities have to be linked to a Azure DC. This primary Azure DC has to be connected to secondary Azure DC.

To elaborate the scenario some more...

**Update**: There are 2 separate things to be done here.

First, hook the 2 datacenters (let's say in Charlotte & Boston) that are already linked through a Point to Point link, to a Azure DC East US. Will this require one or 2 Expressroute circuits? I'm guessing it'll need one at a minimum as they are already linked.

After on-prem DCs & Azure are connected, I would like to setup DR between Azure East US & Azure West US. As there is significant data transfer expected between the 2, I would like to setup ExpressRoute connectivity between Azure East US & Azure West US.

Over time, I plan to migrate all servers in on-prem DCs to Azure & have everything on Azure.

Considering both requirements, what is the minimum number of ExpressRoute circuits I should have?

---

I'm considering an ExpressRoute circuit between Azure Primary DC & Azure Secondary DC in the same geopolitical region for Disaster Recovery as the data transfer between them could be significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To rephrase, 2 linked DCs in separate cities have to be linked to a
>   Azure DC. This primary Azure DC has to be connected to secondary Azure
>   DC.

Do you mean you want to connect Azure primary DC and Azure secondary DC with ExpressRoute? And you want to know how many circuits needed?

If I understand it correctly, you **just** want to connect Azure primary DC and secondary DC with ExpressRoute, I think you need **one** circuit.
 If you want to connect your other DCs to connect to Azure DC, one connection to Azure needs one circuit.
Each Express Route circuit has a redundant pair of cross connections configured to provide high availability.

==================================================
**Update**:

> I want to connect 2 on-prem DCs to one Azure DC (east us) with ER.
>   After that is established, i want a Azure primary DC to Azure
>   secondary DC connection for DR

We need at least **one** circuit for connect 2 on-prems DCs to one Azure DC. same as this [screenshot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-connectivity-models#a-nameipvpnaany-to-any-ipvpn-networks):

> You can integrate your WAN with the Microsoft cloud. IPVPN providers
>   (typically MPLS VPN) offer any-to-any connectivity between your branch
>   offices and datacenters. The Microsoft cloud can be interconnected to
>   your WAN to make it look just like any other branch office. WAN
>   providers typically offer managed Layer 3 connectivity. ExpressRoute
>   capabilities and features are all identical across all of the above
>   connectivity models.

[image]

Then you want to connect Azure primary DC to Azure secondary DC, we need at least **one** circuit.

**So, at least it require 2 ExpressRoute circuits.**

Comment: Thanks @jason-ye-msft for your response. I have added more details to my question. Can you plz take a look

Comment: Do you mean you have two on-prem DCs and two Azure DCs, you want to connect  2 on-prem DCs to one Azure DC (east us)? if yes, to connect them you need 2 circuits. If you want your 2 on-prem DCs to connect to Azure secondary DC, you need add another 2 circuits, `one connection to Azure needs one circuit`. Other way, if you want to connect Azure DC to Azure DC, we can use S2S VPN,

Comment: Yes. I want to connect 2 on-prem DCs to one Azure DC (east us) with ER. After that is established, i want a Azure primary DC to Azure secondary DC connection for DR (NOT 2 on-prem DCs to Azure secondary DC as at some point the 2 on-prem DCs would be decommissioned). That would require 2 ExpressRoute circuits, right?

Comment: @mvp your are right, we need 2 circuits at least, I have update my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to reduce number of ER circuits, you can use one ER in its own dedicated subscription per region, then attach to vnets across multiple subscriptions and multiple Azure vdc's from there.  This is called shared provider subscription model, and you maintain via ER circuit owner/user authorizations blade to create the connection authorizations between subscriptions.